# Are there known ways to posit definable global choice in ZF without positing V=L?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, definability

I need a global choice function defined by a formula in (a fragment of) ZF.  There is no harm in assuming V=L for my purposes.  But I wonder if there are any familiar alternative ways to get this?

The comments make see I also want a weakened part of GCH.  Namely the power set of  $\aleph_n,\ n\in\mathbb{N}$ should be $\aleph_m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$.  I see that HOD is known compatible with some extreme failure of CH, but I have not found what.  Is it compatible with failure of this weakened part of GCH?

Comment: You can always assume V=HOD (the latter the hereditarily ordinal definable sets). Indeed HOD is the largest class for which there exists a definable bijection with the class of ordinals. See for example, Drake or Jech's book.

Comment: To follow up on Philp Welch's comment: see the following posting by Joel Hamkins: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180727/is-it-consistent-with-zfc-or-zf-that-every-definable-family-of-sets-has-at-lea/180734#180734

Comment: You can force global choice over any model of $ZFC$ without adding any new sets.

Comment: @Colin :  You can, consistently relative to ZF, have full GCH in HOD if you wish, or else weak failures of the kind ($\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit) you mention.

Comment: @Mohammad: To be accurate, global choice can be forced over models of $\sf NBG+AC$ without adding sets. Doing this over models of $\sf ZFC$ requires us to extend the language by adding a the generic class. Sure, this is not an actual issue, but it's more accurate this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Two comments/answers:

**(1)** By an old theorem of Roguski, for any $\Sigma_2^{\text{ZFC}}$ sentence $\phi$, the  theories $\text{ZFC} + \phi$ and $\text{ZFC + V=HOD} + \phi$ are equiconsistent.

Roguski's result appears in his paper *Extensions of models for ZFC to models for ZF+V=HOD with applications*, in Set theory and hierarchy theory, pp. 241–247. Lecture Notes in Math., Vol. 537, Springer, Berlin, 1976.

**(2)** Since there is a parenthetical reference to fragments of $\text{ZF}$ in the first line of the question: the formulation and salient consequences of $\text{V=HOD}$ heavily depend on stratification of the universe into rank initial segments of the form $V_\alpha$, and on the veracity of the Montague-Levy reflection theorem; the latter is equivalent over $\text{ZF}$ without $\{\text{Replacement, Infinity}\}$ to the conjunction of $\text{Replacement}$ and $\text{Infinity}$ (by an old result of Azriel Levy).

So $\text{V=L}$, rather than $\text{V=HOD}$, is the safe way to arrange global choice, at least for fragments of $\text{ZF}$ that extend Kripke-Platek set theory.